# How to read / get values from node's field using JavaScript in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, drupal, view, drupal-theming

Let's say I have three field machine names in Drupal on a content type in Drupal:

`company_color_schema` , `company_logo` , and `company_some_picture`

I would like to retrieve the `company_color_schema` which will give me a plain text hex color code using JavaScript so that I can use it for a div background color.

Is there a way to access these values using JavaScript? I've looked at available documentation, but none seems to cover it.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to place JavaScript code in a view template file, at least part of it. So let's say you have a JavaScript row like this:

```
<?php $value_you_get_from_php = ... ; ?>

    <script>
        var bcgColor = <?php echo $value_you_get_from_php; ?>;
    </script>
```

So you'll get your color field value from PHP and print it out inside inline JavaScript code, exactly at position where you defined your JavaScript variable value. Then you can use that JavaScript variable anywhere you need it.

Another way would be making an Ajax call with i.e. the node id as parameter, but the first option is easier, if it's acceptable.

Or, the easiest solution (inspired by Artreaktor's answer): Just shoot color directly from a template file - add the `style` tag attribute and set color from that. Artreaktor's solution may be more by rules, but mine is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [drupalSettings](https://www.drupal.org/node/304258) for this.

You can attach them in [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x) or similar depending on your needs

Actually, you don't need javascript to set div background. The better way is to use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x):

```
mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['background'] = $vars['node'][WHATEVER_VALUE];
}
```

Put this code into your module, clear caches and then you can use `$background` variable in your `node.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yes. In drupal 8:

1. Create a view, build it's query to show your fields
2. Go to Admin/extend and enable "RESTful Web Services" module
3. Add REST export display to it
4. Create path for your REST export display
5. select format "serializer" with settings:

   - Force using fields - checked;
   - json - checked;
6. You're pretty done. Ajax the url in your script, parse the JSON and you have your fields in JS.